# Message from the cloud to a machine behind NAT / Firewall

Tags: http, cloud, firewall, skype, nat

I want a cloud machine to send a message to a machine behind a corporate NAT / Firewall.

My idea is to install on the corporate machine a client which sends a long HTTP request to the cloud machine and when the cloud has a message it returns the response.

I thought I invented the wheel until I read about "http tunneling" (is this what I am doing?).
I also read that some firewalls block non html traffic even if it is on http.
So what is my chance to make it work?

I have also read that skype uses a more sophisticated machanism.
Is it because my idea does not work or because their idea is faster?

I can compromise on speed now - which approach works and easy to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you'd like to do it with TCP/HTTP,
but the way I'd do it is use UDP to
NAT 'hole punch', thus establishing a UDP channel,
and then use UDP packets sent over that
channel as the signaling mechanism...

These may (or may not) be useful or relevant:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching
```

Also -- if you really have to use HTTP, you could 
simply issue a new HTTP request every X seconds...

HTTP Polling, if you will...

Comment: what is the advantage - performance? less chance to be detected?

Comment: also how do I do it - do I need some library or should I implement it myself?

Comment: If you go the UDP approach -- you basically need to be able to send and receive UDP packets on both ends.  I can't suggest any libraries for this -- although I know plenty exist.  (I'm mostly a Delphi programmer -- so I'd probably use the Indy library or 'roll-my-own' using Winsock -- which by the way leads me to a book recommendation -- there's a Winsock book with examples in C/C++ (as I recall) by Quinn and Shute... that's the book you want.  If this is for Unix, you can't go wrong with "Unix Network Programming" by W. Richard Stevens...

Comment: what is the advantage of this approach? it seems more complex to implement so I am looking for motivation...

Comment: UDP's advantage is speed and being a 'lower level' network protocol than TCP/IP... UDP is 'connectionless', i.e., there's no guarantee provided by the protocol that you'll get X bytes in Y seconds, but to get around this I'd simply have the server send a UDP packet with a status flag at an interval you choose, if your client doesn't get one in this interval -- the client can then go (via HTTP or whatever) to the server and check for new stuff.  For a lightweight signaling protocol, UDP is great.

Comment: I guess I'd try the simpler and easier to implement HTTP approach first, if it serves your needs, by all means go with it.

Answer (score 2):

If they block non html on port 80, you could try port 443. Unless there is a SSL "man in the middle" proxy (unlikely), you'd be ok.

IIRC skype uses port hopping, so basically you'll need an algorithm to find an unfiltered (by brute force with intelligent guesses) port that you can connect to.